# Parse.com: database query performance between Number and String

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, database

I'm using Parse.com in my app and I'm wondering if there is a significant performance difference in queries for types Number and String. For strings there won't be any search for substrings, only comparisons.

In my table, the values are predefined, so I can use numbers to represent the values, but I find this approach very unorganized. I prefer using the actual strings, but I'm afraid this will make the queries slower.

Does anyone have information about this performance issue?

Thanks.

Comment: No. Test it. How big are your queries that this is a concern?

Comment: The table will grow about 400 rows/day